# mongodb shopping cart expiration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, e-commerce

i'm just curious what the best practice would be for implementing shopping cart expiration for a mongo backed e-commerce site. i would like to use something like TTL to have the product automatically removed from any shopping carts that have expired. HOWEVER, it doesn't look like TTL takes a callback, so producing useful side effects isn't really an option (that i know of.)

so with that said, should i have a loop that runs every time a request is made to the product page that goes and checks for expired items and then updates the quantity of said product accordingly? or will that be a big performance hit since it happens on page load?

the alternative i'm considering is using a cron job type node module to regularly redistribute the product distribution based on cart, product expiration times.

anybody have advice on what is the most performant and sane way to implement this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you storing your shopping cart data? A normal pattern is to have temporary data stored in a session with an associated expiry date. You could use TTL to automatically cleanup old session data based on the expiry date. I would definitely avoid the "Poor man's cron" approach of checking for expired items on page load. You also mention callbacks - aside from deleting the expired cart data, what other "useful side effects" are you after?

Comment: so i inherited this code and it has collections for **products** and **users** and **carts**. a cart is linked to a user and products can be placed in a cart. there is a session cookie but its not being used for the cart functionality. what i want is to have **products** expire after 48 hours of being in a **cart**, thereby incrementing  the specific **product** inventory back up the correct number of items. what if i added a field to every **product** that tracks which carts its in and when they expire? then when the specific product is requested, i call a function to collect expired items?